# In Ann Leckie's The Raven Tower, does the narrarator contradict itself?

Tags: the-raven-tower

After the war for the strait, the Raven apparently sets up

> Strength and Patience's machinery

so that it has to use its own power to maintain it. But later, the narrator says that

> it had been draining the Raven's power while simultaneously fulfilling its obligations.

Is this a contradiction, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the narrator did not contradict themselves - the situation was in a state of conflict.

In Ard Vusktia, Strength and Patience spoke that he would grant the requests of whomever turned him. The Raven was having him turned, and thus Strength and Patience was fulfilling the Raven's obligations on his behalf.

However, Strength and Patience also said this:

> The Raven said he had spoken the deaths of all the gods who fought for Ard Vusktia, but even with the power of every small god of Iraden, even having taken all the God of the Silent Forest had, he could not make those words true. I still lived, and the Myriad as well. The ancient gods are, I have been told, difficult to kill.

So, as long as Strength and Patience lived, what the Raven spoke could not be true, which would drain his power.

So - keeping Strength and Patience and using him to fullfill his obligations was both simultaneously helping *and* hurting the Raven.